# Ubuntu 14.04 re-installation - Installing updates from the Internet is taking more than 12 hours

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 due to my memory (RAM) was getting full with information, affecting my pc. I had my computer running Ubuntu 14.04. I picked the option to remove the previous Ubuntu and reinstall.

This time, I allowed it to install all updates through my Internet connection. My problem is that I have stood in the notice page for at least 12 hours. Should I be worried about something being wrong? My Internet connection hasn't been interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd. The installer might have crashed or something.

I advise you to shut down your computer (you can just pull the electricity plug if it really has crashed) and try installing again. If the problem occurs again then don't allow the updates. Run the updater after the installation finishes. It's totally the same.

Comment: I have now tried that yet the result is the same. Waited for 10h. The following message had come up though before clicking install now: "the attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI (0,0,0) partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed

Comment: so you tried installing without updating but it still didn't work?!